# How can I redirect only main page to https and without www?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect only main page to https and without www?

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
http://mywebsite.com
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

All of URLs above should redirect once to:

```
https://mywebsite.com
```

Everything inside subdirectories should stay intact

```
https://mywebsite.com/website-in-progress
```

I am trying various code I have found but I didn't find anything to work all cases.

**EDIT**: This seems to be working visually great, the problem is that some URLs have multiple redirects

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The outcome of this is:

```
- https://mywebsite.com/ - OK
- https://www.mywebsite.com/ - not desirable, redirects first to http://mywebsite.com and then to https://mywebsite.com
- http://www.mywebsite.com/ - not desirable, redirects first to https://www.mywebsite.com and then to https://mywebsite.com
- http://mywebsite.com/ - OK, redirects once to https://mywebsite.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule as top most rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%1% [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have placed only this code and it doesn't work, page opens under https, but on https://www.. it says invalid response and on http it redirects but without https

Comment: This is a working rule on my live site. If you are not seeing `http->https` redirect or `www` removal then your site is using some other rule not this one.